# Next.js Redux integration Could not find "store" in either the context or props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

I am currently trying to integrate my redux store to my Next.js react applcation. The only issue now is when I try to call connect inside my index.js file.

Maybe it has something to do with the way my app is laid out? I tried console.log(this.props) inside index.js but it doesn't seem to have anything sent down from provider.

Error:
Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Page)". Either wrap the root component in a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Page)".

page.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store/store';
import Head from './head'
import Nav from './nav'

const childPage = (ChildPage) => {
    return (
        class Page extends React.Component {
            render() {
                return (
                    <Provider store={store}>
                        <div>
                            <Head />
                            <Nav />
                            <ChildPage />
                        </div>
                    </Provider>
                )
            }
        }
    )
}

export default childPage;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Page from '../components/page';

export class Index extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="hero">

        </div>
        <style jsx>{`

        `}</style>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(state => state)(Page(Index));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure order was incorrect.

```
export default connect(state=>state)(Page(Index));
```

This leads to `connect() > Provider > Index`

```
export default Page(connect(state=>state)(Index));
```

This leads to `Provider > connect() > Index`

So the answer is to do it like this:

```
export default Page(connect(state=>state)(Index));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next-redux-wrapper` npm package. Add `withRouter` hoc on `_app.js` page of your app.

Here is example: https://github.com/galishmann/nextjs-redux-example/blob/master/pages/_app.js